# Facebook Open Graph- Dynamic Title

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a social app that requires some Open Graph actions.
I want the meta data tag for the title to be from my database because the name of my action title depends on the user choice.

Is it possible to get the title meta from database, rather than being hard coded? For instance:

```
<meta property="og:title"  content="<?php echo $someTitle ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is *possible* – but how to you want to know *what* content to put out *when*?

When Facebook scrapes your URL, your site’s user is not involved. So that means you have to transfer some info via the query string or something; and that would make them *different* URLs, so you’ll end up with different OG objects as well.

Comment: i tried to get the title from my DB. the problem is that the title does not change and it seems like facebook gets my title from Cache instead of getting it from my data base

Comment: While publishing an action, you can „force” Facebook to re-scrape the URL – see docs for how.